# Error “Code: 0x0000000A” while installing Windows 7 in VM

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization

I have Windows 10 on a PC that I built myself. I'm trying to install a VM with Windows 7, I cannot find the option to turn on virtualization anywhere in the BIOS. The only thing even related to Virtual machines is "Secure Virtual Machine Mode." I have an AMD Athlon II x4 620 processor if that matters.

[image: VirtualBox settings]

Comment: 24 MB of VRAM? You should increase that too.

Comment: Also, what mobo do you have?

Comment: increase it to what?

Comment: Maybe 128 MB but, what's your mobo?

Comment: i got it to work, but i also dont know how to check that :/

Comment: Try enabling 'secure virtual machine mode' and tell me if it works.

Comment: yeah it worked lol

Comment: now im getting stuck in a loop? when i try installing windows it says needs to restart, so it does and then ends up back at the inital setup windows page?

Comment: For now, if I have solved the question, please accept my answer. You should ask another question about your new problem.

Comment: Please clarify what this question is about. Is it about enabling hardware-assisted virtualization? Is it about not being able to install Windows 7? What did you do? How exactly did you do it?

Comment: @DanielB I believe he was asking how to enable AMD-V in his BIOS. That's why I've told them to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [here](http://vip.asus.com/forum/view.aspx?board_id=1&model=M4A77TD%20PRO&id=20091104070321500&page=1&SLanguage=en-us), the `Secure Virtual Machine Mode` is what to click to enable AMD-V virtualization.